# Reading logfile with javascript. How to format the log?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Im making an program with Python that parses a file and logs the changes to the file. Now my issue is that what format would be the best way to store this information so it would be usable with Javascript on the local machine. The goal is to generate offline html-files that will show log in formatted list and also as a graph.

JSON has good qualities, but I think it will heavy later on to write the whole JSON file over and over again.

"Normal" type of logfile is simple to append to end of the file, but im bit unsure what is the best way of accessing this kind of data with Javascript.

The log file will be maximum maybe ten thousands of rows.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post here some code if you had, thanks!

Comment: Im first trying to see what would be the best approach to do the logging so it would be in sensible format to be used with javascript. I have my Python code ready to write the log when I can settle for a format.

Comment: you could have each line in the log file be JSON instead of the whole file so then you don't have to rewrite the whole file every time but its still easy to read it/parse into a javascript array

Comment: Good point, even though im not quite sure how to parse multiple json-objects from one file?

Comment: Please add the code you tried, or it is very likely that this question will eventually get closed.

Answer (score 1):

For easy parsing in Javascript JSON would be just fine. But if the end result is to have "offline logs in HTML" then why not just output HTML in the first place?

Other lightweight formats that are easy to parse could be TSV/CSV.

Comment: CSV actually seem quite obvious choice, not sure why it didnt come into my mind. It would be quite easily usable in other places then too.